# Display parts of widgets tree dynamically inside Column/Row or CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So in my code, I have a CustomScrollView which displays some static widgets, and the rest are dynamic widgets, so for example for each tab , I would show a bunch of specific widgets, but the problem with my code, if I want to extract those dynamic widgets into a seperate widget, I will have to wrap them with CustomScrollView or some widget with children property because I can't return just one widget I need multiple widgets to be returned from that custom widget, So I fall in the problem of nesting CustomScrollView inside CustomScrollView while I have only a single scrollable CustomScrollView if u understand what I mean, the following example explains my code, so is there a workaround this problem if somoene could help.

```
List<Widget> _widgets = [FirstWidget(),SecondWidget(),ThirdWidget()];
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: SizedBox(height: 10),
              ),
              const SliverToBoxAdapter(child:Container()),
              _widgets[index],
 );
}

FirstWidget extends StatelessWidget{
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return CustomScrollView(
         slivers:[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child:Text("First Widget"));
           SliverList(......);
     ]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top level widget already handling scroll event, you can return `Column` widget to return multiple widget.

```dart
  return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      const SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SizedBox(height: 10),
      ),
    
      _widgets[1],
    ]);
```

```dart
class FirstWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("First Widget"),
        ...List.generate(33, (index) => Text("item $index"))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```